# What is =C in bash?

Tags: bash

I read in a script somewhere :

```
a_var=C ls
```

I tried it. This executes `ls` (I see the content of the current directory) and leaves `a_var` empty. What is this `=C` in bash ? It is the first time I see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will set the environment-variable `a_var` to `"C"` in the environment `ls` runs in. Most likely this was used to actually set the collation `ls` uses to influence sorting (`LANG=C ls` or `LC_COLLATE=C ls`).

Using C as collation for `ls` will sort files case-sensitive, meaning files starting with a-z come after A-Z. SOme other collations may have additional rules, such as ignoring dots or treating umlauts as vowels - `C` doesn't have anything like this.

Comment: As a demo experiment, try running this: `foo=bar bash -c 'echo $foo'`. In the inner environment (the `bash` we're running), it prints `bar`. However, in the outer environment (the `bash` we're running it *from*), it is still undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The line `var_a=C ls` is a bash command.

Any Bash command can set environment variables local to the commands executing environment, these environment variables (`var_a` in your case) won't exist after execution. This is, for example, often used when running `make` to specify options like a different compiler than the default, or in `curl` like so:

```
$ CC=~/bin/my_own_cc make
$ http_proxy=http://proxy_server:8080 curl http://www.google.com
```

When run like this, `make` will user `~/bin/my_own_cc` instead of the default C compiler and `curl` will know to use a proxy when retrieving `http://google.com`.

These commands will not pollute the executing environment with otherwise unnecessary variables.

That said, in your example, this doesn't have any side effects.